# How do I set a RestorationClass in a Xamarin.iOS UIViewController without storyboards?

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

From [tutorials like this](http://aplus.rs/2013/state-restoration-in-ios-6-without-storyboards/), I know that I need to set the `RestorationIdentifier` and `RestorationClass` on my view controllers in order to get state restoration to work without storyboards, but I can't figure out how to set the `RestorationClass` in my view controller.

Objective-C examples do `self.RestorationClass = [self class]`, but my attempted C# translation `RestorationClass = this` produces the error **Cannot implicitly convert type `Foo` to `ObjCRuntime.Class`**. How do I work around this error?

[Repo with my working, minimal example](https://github.com/asasha/StateRestoration)

Comment: Do you still have a sample project? I know how to call RestorationClass but I don't know the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want code like this to create a Class object for the Type:

```
this.RestorationClass = new ObjCRuntime.Class(typeof(BViewController));
```